# python telegram AIOGRAM : клавиатура в общий чат

Tags: python, telegram, бот, aiogram

Всем добрый день, подскажите помогите как сделать выдачу клавиатуры в общий чат группы
как например у manybot/grouphelp.
[image: пример]

Comment: у manybot дополнительно реализовано в меню KeyboardButton общего чата

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: чтобы получить клавиатуру в групповом чате как у ManyBot сразу при вступлении в группу
@dp.message_handler(content_types=[ContentType.NEW_CHAT_MEMBERS])
async def new_members_handler(message: types.Message):
    new_member = message.new_chat_members[0]
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Добро пожаловать, {new_member.mention}', reply_markup=Название клавиатуры)

Comment: для кнопок в групповом чате 
InlineKeyboardMarkup
keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
menu_1 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Расписание ', url="https://github.com")
menu_2 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Программы ', url="https://github.com")
menu_3 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='О проекте  ', url="https://github.com")
keyboard.add(menu_1, menu_2, menu_3)

Comment: просто читайте мануалы, учусь . всем спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Говорят 5 часов программирования сэкономят 5 минут чтения документации :)
Лучше правда прочитай.)

```
#Создадим CallBack-функцию для Inline кнопки:
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='OpenInPM_cbk')
async def I_btn(callback : types.CallbackQuery):
    await callback.answer('Открываю в личном сообщении.') 
    # Не пропускай это, если бот получает эту асинхронную модель, он понимает, что каллбек вызвался.
    # Если хочешь чтобы ничего не показывало, заполни как во второй кнопке.

    # Тут опишешь всё что тебе нужно. (Будет срабатывать при нажатии на кнопку)

@dp.callback_query_handler(text='OpenHere_cbk')
async def I_btn(callback : types.CallbackQuery):
    await callback.answer('') 

#Опишем Inline кнопки:
Buttons = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1) # Это как-раз фолдер кнопок. row_width - количестко кнопок которое может поместиться в одной строке.
#Если ты указал row_width, при добавлении в фолдер самих снопок можешь использовать метод .row, вместо .add, таким образом ты сможешь обойти это ограничение.

OpenInPM = InlineKeyboardMarkup(text='Открыть в личке бота', callback_data='OpenInPM_cbk')
OpenHere = InlineKeyboardMarkup(text='Открыть здесь', callback_data='OpenHere_cbk')

Buttons.add(OpenInPM, OpenHere)

# Наконец вызовем сообщение с кнопками: Бот будет реагировать на 'Открыть бота'

async def polling(message : types.Message):
    if message.text == 'Открыть бота':
       await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Где вы хотите открыть меню настроек?', reply_markup = Buttons)
```

Comment: да спасибо, я разобрался почитав мануалы